# Parsing with sscanf

Tags: parsing, scanf

Good day, I tried parsing this query string:

```
pkname=Paras&key=password123
```

with this code:

```
printf("Content-type:text/html\n\n");

printf("<html><body>"); 

data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");

if(data){
    sscanf(data, "pkname=%10[^&]&key=%30[^&]&", pkname, key);

    printf("%s", pkname);
    printf("%s", key);

}

printf("</html></body>");
```

But i can't seem to get the key right, since the its output is always null:

```
Paras(null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the definition of the variable `key` but the fact that it prints out as `(null)` strongly suggests that its value is NULL, and that both `printf` and `sscanf` are trying to protect you by not segfaulting on NULL pointers. (The GNU libc implementations do that; printf prints NULL as `(null)` and sscanf appears to just stop parsing.)

What you probably wanted was something like:

```
char pkname[11];
char key[31];
```

although you might also find the `m` qualifier useful, since it avoids the need to specify arbitrary field length limits.